# How to represent c# setter in UML sequence diagram?

Tags: c#, uml, sequence-diagram

I will like to set values in a property `Scores`. How do I draw this in UML sequence diagram? May I clarify if the diagram drawn below is correct?

**Code (C#):**

From file: Test.cs

```
public class Test<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Scores { get; set; }
}
```

From file: TestScore.cs

```
public class TestScore
{
    List<int> numList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Test<int> test = new Test<int>();
    test.Scores = numList;
}
```

**UML Sequence Diagram:**

[image: Sequence diagram]

Comment: `Scores {get; set;}` equals to `getScores();  setScores()` functions.

Comment: @Li-JyuGao Meaning the arrow for test.Scores.set() should point to the activation of test:Test<int> instead right?

Comment: an interaction (e.g. sequence diagram) is not the right way to show that, look at activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Is the diagram correct ?

No, this diagram is not correct.  The following initialization in class `TestScore`:

```
test.Scores = numList;
```

would be a `set(numList)` message that `:TestScore` sends to `test`,  because `:TestScore` invokes the setter of `test`.

Since in fact it is the setter of `test.Scores` that is in reality invoked, you could even consider `setScores(numList)` to avoid any ambiguity if the class `Test`  would evolve to expose other  setters.

### 2. Is the diagram a good idea ?

This diagram seems to be very detailed. Maybe too detailed. The sequence diagram is not intended to be graphical programming, but to document a (complex?) interaction scenario between classes.

The purpose is to facilitate understanding of an implementation or a design involving object interactions.   **Whenever the code is easier to understand than the graph**, you should question yourself if you’re not overengineering the problem, and also think about the effort required in future to update the graph whenever the code evolves. You alone can judge if it’s worth the effort.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your answer and advice.

Comment: Shouldn't the call be `setScores`?

Comment: @qwerty_so this is a very valid remark! I hesitated and kept the simpler form because I viewed Test to be a simple wrapper for the scores container. But indeed, a full class which could have other properties, should disambiguate the get/set by adding the receiving member. I’ve edited accordingly. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Usually the compiler translates that construct internally to `get<prop>` as a function returning <prop> and `set<prop>(val)` setting <prop> to val. We called that syntactical sugar.